# Is there a way to set icon size for multiple icons at once (i.e. all the icons within a widget) in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, icons

I've got a widget that has multiple icons from various different sources, and I'm wanting to increase the size of the icons.

The sizes only have to increase within this one widget, but not elsewhere, so I can't just resize the .png file the icons are based off of.

Is it possible to refer to every icon within a widget using a for-loop and then do something like `button1->setIconSize(QSize(100, 100));` in the body of the loop? I haven't been able to find any attributes of any type of widget that allows you to access all the icons within that widget

I'm open to any ideas at all

Comment: Maybe you want `auto lstButtons = pWidget->findChildren<QPushButton*>();` to get all the buttons. Here is the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren after you have the list use a range based for loop to iterate over the list. `for(auto btn : lstButtons) { // do something with btn}`

Comment: Sometimes QSS can do the trick, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an example for you

```
btn1 = new QToolButton(this);
btn2= new QToolButton(this);
btn3 = new QToolButton(this);

btn1->setFixedSize(80,80);
btn2->setFixedSize(80,80);
btn3->setFixedSize(80,80);

QIcon icon1;
iconRe.addFile(QString::fromUtf8("path/icon.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
btn1->setIcon(icon1);
btn1->setIconSize(QSize(24, 24));

QIcon icon2;
iconte.addFile(QString::fromUtf8("path/icon.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
btn2->setIcon(icon2);
btn2->setIconSize(QSize(50, 50));


QIcon icon3;
icondelete.addFile(QString::fromUtf8("path/icon.png"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
btn3->setIcon(icon3);
btn3->setIconSize(QSize(70, 70));
```

the result was such

[image]